# Adding AD users as an Admin

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Here's the situation. I'm am completely new to PowerShell so use small words...

I have a new user in Active Directory that I need to add to about 100 computers as efficiently as possible. My hope was that I could make a PowerShell script that would add the user either through a login script or remotely. I need to have a bit of precision control over this deployment because we don't want to push this user to every computer in the company.

Can PowerShell help me with this, and if not do you all have some sage advice that could help?

Comment: I'd suggest creating a domain group and adding this person to the group and then adding that group to the servers instead. Will make it easier if you ever need to do it again in the future (just add new user to ad group).

Answer (score 0):

To add a user to the local administrators group using PowerShell:

```
([ADSI]"WinNT://./Administrators,group").Add("WinNT://your-domain/new-user,user")
```

Just replace the `your-domain` and `new-user` parts of the command with the appropriate values for your environment.